# in php read text file and insert file data into mysql line by line but they read one row they cannot read complete file

Tags: php

I have a problem I need some code in PHP the read txt file line by line and insert all data into MySQL database but this code read all data and insert only single row please anyone can help me to solve this problem.

Note: I need a code that is read text file line by line and insert all data into MySQL database and i insert large txt file data into MySQL database so please anyone can help me

```
$file = fopen("members.txt", "r");

    while (!feof($file)) {
             $line_of_text= fgets($file);

             $mem .= explode("\n", $line_of_text);           
        }
  list($cname,$std,$longtext)=$mem;

  $t=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$longtext);

$sql=mysqli_query($con,"INSERT into test(class,student,info) values('$cname','$std','$t')");

        fclose($file);
        print_r($mem);
```

Comment: Before you solve your question, you really need to look up SQL injection attacks. rather than trying to escape the code yourself, you need to use parameterised queries. It is considerably safer.

Answer (score 0):

Put your INSERT inside your loop, otherwise you will only insert the last row in the loop.